# How to find amounts greater than zero before a specified date

Tags: t-sql, date, interbase

Currently I am trying to find the outstanding balance of an account before a certain specified date.

below is my query

```
SELECT 
    TRANS.AMTUNRES UNPAID,
    TRANS.TRANTYPE,
    TRANS.INCPROVCODE IPROV,
    ACHOLDERACH.ACBALANCE BALANCE,
    ACHOLDERANY.PREFORMATTEDINTERN ACCOUNTNAMECHART,
    WHENPAY,
    ChartNo

FROM   TRANS
  LEFT JOIN ACHOLDER ACHOLDERACH ON ACHOLDERACH.ACHOLDERID = TRANS.ACHOLDERID
  LEFT JOIN ANYBODY ACHOLDERANY ON ACHOLDERANY.ANYBODYID = TRANS.ACHOLDERID
  LEFT JOIN INVPAYRESOLN ON ACHOLDERACH.ACHOLDERID = INVPAYRESOLN.ACHOLDERID
  left join anybody on trans.anybodyid = anybody.anybodyid

   where TRANS.AMTUNRES <> '0.00'  and
    ACHOLDERACH.ACBALANCE <> '0.00' and
    WhenPay between '01-01-2012' and '04-07-2016'

and chartNo = '123456789'
```

Comment: and what is the expected and actual output?

Comment: I am trying to find records where their balance is not equal to 0 before a certain date but have paid now.

Comment: Are you talking about running total on Balance field?